# how to send a tuple value as an arg to a function started as a thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, arguments

I have a class function that I want to start up as a thread.  The function takes as its argument a tuple value.  The function works fine but my initial setup throws a TypeError.  Here's some sample code:

```
import threading

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.msg, args=(2,1))
        t.start()
        print "started thread"

    # msg takes a tuple as its arg (e.g. tupleval = (0,1))
    def msg(self,tupleval):
        if(tupleval[0] > 1):
            print "yes"
        else:
            print "no"


test = Test()
test.msg((2,2))
test.msg((0,0))
```

and then the output is as follows:

```
started thread
yes
no
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 532, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 484, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
TypeError: msg() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

It appears to work for the two explicit calls at the end, but the initial setup call throws the TypeError.  I've tried packing values into a tuple in all sorts of ways but can't get rid of the error.  Ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`args` takes a tuple of arguments to pass to the function.  When you say `args=(2,1)` you're not telling it to call `msg` with a single argument `(2,1)`; you're telling it to call it with two arguments, `2` and `1`.

You want `args=((2,1),)`.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to look really ugly, but I believe it should be `args=((2,1),)` (or `args=[(2,1)]` might look slightly nicer).

`args` is supposed to be a tuple of all the arguments to the function, so to pass a tuple, you need a tuple of a tuple. In addition, Python requires you to add the extra comma for a tuple with one element to differentiate it from just wrapping an expression with parentheses.